# Where is the params hash actually set and what is its scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been happily using Rails for quite some time and merrily accepted the use of the params hash but I've suddenly realised that I've missed something fundamental.

It's not an object passed into my actions, it's not prefixed with an @ to make it have object-level scope but it is available to other methods in my controller.

Where are its values set and what is its scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` is currently a method in the ActionController::StrongParameters module that takes its values from `request.parameters`. (There are similarly named methods in other modules, but that's the one you use in a normal controller that inherits from ActionController::Base.)

Comment: Of course, of course. That little bit of syntactic sugar confused the heck out of me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can shed some light here. I am not exactly sure where the params is set, but it is very early in the request processing, way before it gets to your code.

There are three groups in the parameters: User parameters (the stuff you usually care about), Routing Parameters (based on url i.e.: /users/1)and Default parameters (controller and action)

The parameters are available within the **controller only** using params[], but you can always pass this along to a method in a model. Though this is bad practice to pass the entire hash.

Usually you would set local variable and pass them to methods or assign them to instance variables (@foo = params[:foo]) if you want them available in a view.